# TypeError with Select2 script in Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning-web-components

When I use the third-party library `select2.js` in a lightning web component, the console throw an error:

> *TypeError: Illegal invocation*  on column 9251 in select2.min.js : `r.call(e.element,":disabled")

The `select2` seems to work without clicking to show the dropdown.

My HTML code:

```
<select class="address" data-name="select" lwc:dom="manual"></select>
<div data-name="dropdown" lwc:dom="manual"></div>
```

My `renderedCallBack` method in the JavaScript file :

```
 renderedCallback(){
    Promise.all([
        loadScript(this, url + '/assets/jquery-3.4.1.min.js')
    ])
    .then(() => {
        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, url + '/assets/select2.min.js')
        ])
        .then(() => {
            const data = [{
                 id: '1',
                 text: 'Acme'
            },
             {
                 id: '2',
                 text: 'Aperture'
            }]
            $(this.template.querySelector('[data-name="select"]')).select2({
                data: data,
                dropdownParent: $(this.template.querySelector('[data-name="dropdown"]')), 
                debug: true,
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: What is an version of select2?

Comment: When i disable Lightning Locker, the select2 works. Is there a solution to let the Lightning Locker on ? 
Select2 js : https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js